# transform base_link<->map not available, but both base_link<->odom and odom<->map are available (???)

Tags: navigation, odometry, mapping, base-link, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm using stage and slam_gmapping.
Frame hierarchy is: `/map->/odom->/base_footprint->/base_link->/base_laser_link`.

I need to do some operations with the occupancy grid and the laser scan, and I need the position of the robot wrt the map.

Whenever I ask for the robot position (using the tf_echo program, or in C++ using TransformListener), I'm unable to retrieve the transform base_link<->map.

The error is (when running: `rosrun tf tf_echo base_link map`):
**Exception thrown:Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 4.400000000 but the earliest data is at time 1358007388.064145711, when looking up transform from frame [/map] to frame [/base_link]**

or (if I swap source and target frames):
**Exception thrown:Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/base_link] to frame [/map]**

HOWEVER, when individually looking up transforms map<->odom and odom<->base_link, **both transformations are found**!
How can this be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52067/transform-base_link%3C-%3Emap-not-available,-but-both-base_link%3C-%3Eodom-and-odom%3C-%3Emap-are-available-(???)/) by [federico.ferri](https://answers.ros.org/users/3836/federico.ferri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-01-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the error you get from `rosrun tf tf_echo base_link map`, I would guess that the odom<->map and base_link<->odom transforms are in different time epochs. That would explain why each transform seems to work but trying to concatenate them doesn't.

Can you verify that both the odom<->map and base_link<->odom transforms have similar timestamps (you may need to inspect the output of the /tf topic) or double check whatever node you have that is outputting base_link<->odom ?

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2013-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1